# How to get deprecated interface function to stop showing compiler warning?

Tags: delphi, interface, deprecated, delphi-10-seattle

I have an interface, and a corresponding interfaced object. Among the functions, one of them I have marked as `deprecated` in both the interface and interfaced object:

```
type
  ISomeInterface = interface
    function SomeFunctionName: String; deprecated;
  end;

  TSomeInterface = class(TInterfacedObject, ISomeInterface)
    function SomeFunctionName: String; deprecated;
  end;
```

However, upon compilation, I receive a compiler warning:

> Symbol 'SomeFunctionName' is deprecated

This comes from the definition of the interfaced object, where it says `TSomeInterface = class( ...`. If I remove `deprecated` from the interfaced object, the warning goes away. But I still do want this to be flagged on that function.

What do I need to do to stop this compiler warning while still flagging this as `deprecated`? Should I only flag it on the interface instead of both? Or is there a way to instruct the compiler not to raise a warning?

Comment: Do you get the warning even if your project doesn't call the function?

Comment: @John Exactly, just defining it alone in the interfaced object. But that's the whole point of an interface, it's pointless without implementation. Personally, I would consider this a compiler bug, or in general, something overlooked. I should be able to mark it as `deprecated` in both places without a warning.

Comment: "Or is there a way to instruct the compiler not to raise a warning?" Maybe not the answer you are looking for but could using {$WARNINGS OFF} and {$WARNINGS ON} be of any use?

Comment: @Jerry: if the class is merely the implementation of the interface, and is not used standalone (i.e. you will never call that method directly on a class instance, only indirectly through the interface), there is no need to mark the method of the class as deprecated, as Deltics already said.

Comment: @Rudy That may be true in some cases, but in my case, developers have a choice. Similar to the XML library in Delphi. You can create a `TXmlDocument` component (object), or use an `IXmlDocument` instead. Pretty much the same thing in my case. Just because I have an interface, doesn't automatically mean that I deny the option of using the object instead :-)

Comment: @Jerry: so your class is being used standalone (as class). Then it is probably unavoidable. I agree that this should not generate a warning if you never use the method, but apparently it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There does appear to be a compiler bug (or at least strangely defined behaviour).  However, I think you can achieve what you want without running into that problem.

The compiler problem appears to be that having both an **interface** method and the *implementation* of that method marked as `deprecated` results in the deprecated warning even if that interface method is never actually consumed.

But you do not *need* to mark both.

Mark your **interface** method as deprecated and leave the *implementation* of that method unmarked.  I would also strongly recommend that you make your interface methods **private** or at least **protected** to avoid the possibility of accessing them through object references.

The implementation of the method satisfies the contract that the interface must be implemented.  The deprecated status of the method on the interface is then important only for any code that is consuming the method through that interface.

You will then only receive a warning if you have code that references the deprecated method through the interface reference:

```
type
  ISomeInterface = interface
    function SomeFunctionName: String; deprecated;
    procedure OtherProc;
  end;

  TSomeInterface = class(TInterfacedObject, ISomeInterface)
  private // ISomeInterface
    function SomeFunctionName: String;
    procedure OtherProc;
  end;


// ..

var
  foo: ISomeInterface;
begin
  foo := TSomeInterface.Create;
  foo.SomeFunctionName;  // Will emit the deprecated warning
  foo.OtherProc;        // Will emit no warning
end;
```